# Appending DIV to DIV multiple times - does not appear if repeated

Tags: jquery, html, append

Have gleaned much help from this site from reading the various posts over the years but am a bit stuck on this one and cannot seem to find an answer:

I'm displaying/replacing a drop down list which depends on the type of 'table' selected (via a radio button)

All works great...until I try to display a list that has been displayed before...i.e. when I click on a radio button twice I cannot get it to redisplay the list. I have also tried loading all the DIV HTML into an array and calling that so it must(?) be something to do with the append?

This is the HTML I am using. (The  'max@times' in the HTML is where I replace the list with my dynamically generated content - and creates all the various drop down lists in one shot and does not continually fetch them from the server)

```
<div id="selectarea"></div>
<div id="tables">
 <div id="tables2"><p><select id="select2" class="tables" name="tables2"><option value="">Please Select</option>" & max2times & "</select></p></div>"
 <div id="tables4"><p><select id="select4" class="tables" name="tables4"><option value="">Please Select</option>" & max4times & "</select></p></div>"
 <div id="tables6"><p><select id="select6" class="tables" name="tables6"><option value="">Please Select</option>" & max6times & "</select></p></div>"
 <div id="tables8"><p><select id="select8" class="tables" name="tables8"><option value="">Please Select</option>" & max8times & "</select></p></div>"
 <div id="continue"><p style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" id="now" value="Continue" name="now"></p></div>
</div>
```

My JQuery looks like this and does function ok (I was using the alert just to check that it was firing and the correct value was being passed!)

```
$("input:radio[name=tabletype]").live("click",function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                alert("Button Click " + value);
                $("#selectarea").html("");
                var tblSel = $("#tables"+value);
                $("#selectarea").append(tblSel);
                });
```

Any help/ideas would be gratefully received!!!

Thanks,

GS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append clone of your `div`. otherwise same element reference will get appended so new div will be created.

```
$("input:radio[name=tabletype]").live("click",function() {
                  var value = $(this).val();
                     alert("Button Click " + value);
                      $("#selectarea").html("");
                     var tblSel = $("#tables"+value);
                     $("#selectarea").append(tblSel.clone(true).removeAttr("id"));
                });
```

Comment: Awesome! - thank you so much for that - works great/as advertised now! Would never have sussed that one out by myself - and may help with other parts of my project later too!

Thanks again.

GS

Answer (score 2):

You can use clone to get the whole table inside select area. You can use "html()" instead of emptying the area and appending the content.

```
$("input:radio[name=tabletype]").live("click",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var tblSel = $("#tables"+value);
    $("#selectarea").html(tblSel.clone().removeAttr("id"));
});
```

If you want just the content to be copied inside area, then use "html()" itself like below. It will make sure that div's will be having unique ids i.e. You need not to remove ID from the copied content.

```
$("input:radio[name=tabletype]").live("click",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var tblSel = $("#tables"+value);
    $("#selectarea").html(tblSel.html());
});
```